# Reverse order while displaying linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

I have this code, I input 5 random elements 1,3,5,7,9 from the beginning and then I want to display my linked list (1,3,5,7,9), but it is in reverse order for some odd reason (9,7,5,3,1). Could you point out the problem?

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node * next; };

int n;

int main() {

    // input.
    cout << "please input 5 elements:\n";
    node * head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> n;
        node * curr = new node;
        curr -> data = n;
        curr -> next = head;
        head = curr;
    }


    // display
    while (head) {
        cout << head -> data << "\n";
        head = head -> next;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to print the list backwards?

Comment: Right after I finished adding elements, to verify.

Comment: Its doing exactly what you coded it to do. Start with `head=null`. Create `1`, point to `null` (current head), and update `head=1`. Afterwards, add `3`, point next to `1` (head) and update `head=3`. Add `5`, point next to `3`... etc (5->3->1->null). After you are done, you start from head (5).. print and go to next (3). It helps if you use a piece of paper and annotate whats going to happen step-by-step... it will help you to visualize whats going on,.

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks, albeit linked list topic is very difficult to me to preceive.

Comment: @wendelbsilva That would make a good answer rather than a content.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with recursion.  Using the call stack to keep track of each node you would keep traversing the list.  Once you reach the end then you print and end the function.  This will then propagate back up the call stack printing the next element back up to the start.

```
void print_revers(node* n)
{
    if (n)
        print_reverse(n->next)
    std::cout << n->data << std::endl;
}
```

This example assumes that the last node in the list that `next` points to `NULL` or `nullptr`

Answer (score 1):

That's how your list looks like after each step of inputting data:

1. 1
2. 3->1
3. 5->3->1
4. 7->5->3->1
5. 9->7->5->3->1

If you would like to have the list (1, 3, 5, 7, 9), you would need to insert each element at the end of the list, not in the beginning. So, you would need to have a pointer to the end (it was called a tail, I think) to put the elements in the order you want. The code would look like this:

```
node * head = NULL, * tail = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> n;
    node * curr = new node;
    curr -> data = n;
    curr -> next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = tail = curr;
    }
    else {
        tail -> next = curr;
        tail = tail -> next;
    }
}
```

It should work this way.

Comment: You are correctly appending the list but you never moved the tail to the last node. You will lose track of 3rd and 4th node. It will end up printing 1,3,9.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this. But the general idea works